# Align text to flex box without containing it within the item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve this design

[image]

I used flex box to achieve this but facing some problems to align the contents the way the design demanding
I used self-align property of flex box to align the three items to achieve the steps like design.

My code:

```css
#main {
  background: #fff2fd;
  padding: 120px 0;
}

#main h2 {
  font-family: 'Circular-Std-Bold';
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 50px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#main div.contents {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

#main div.contents div.item {
  width: 32%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#main div.contents div.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#main div.contents div.item div.img-container {
  width: 300px;
}

#main div.contents div.item div.img-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#main div.contents div.item h3 {
  font-family: 'Circular-Std-Bold';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#main div.contents div.item p {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#main div.contents div.item:first-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#main div.contents div.item:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: center;
}

#main div.contents div.item:last-child {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="main">
    <section class="wrapper">
      <h2>how patch works for everyone involved?</h2>
      <div class="contents">
        <div class="item bottom">
          <div class="img-container"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/26bwqT5/image1.png" alt="image" /></div>
          <h3>patch can you a new deposit or unlock an existing one</h3>
          <p>giving tenants choice to spend their money on whatever they like</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item middle">
          <div class="img-container"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/C9DNWWh/image2.png" alt="image" /></div>
          <h3>patch can you a new deposit or unlock an existing one</h3>
          <p>giving tenants choice to spend their money on whatever they like</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item top">
          <div class="img-container"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ZT6f77F/image3.png" alt="image" /></div>
          <h3>patch can you a new deposit or unlock an existing one</h3>
          <p>giving tenants choice to spend their money on whatever they like</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
```

I'm having trouble to aligning text with the third item where the text says "the how patch works for everyone involved?" Are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/jopevulolu/edit?css,output). You can fine-tune it as per your requirements.

Comment: yeah it's works!! how to do it with flex is i need to position the third item

Comment: just put your h2 into the bottom item -> wrap content of that item into some div.containter -> set space-between prop

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the image with the text (it seems that's the main difference) you simply need to change your selector:

```
#main div.contents div.item div.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Then you'll have to fix the size of each block, giving it a fixed width or working with padding.

I hope this was what you meant.

Comment: sorry i think my question confused you i mean align the third flex item centrally with the text with h2 element which outside the flexbox container